# Origin value for UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I'd like to scroll my `UITableView` up when the keyboard is displayed so the textfields are not covered by the keyboard. I know how to scroll the tableView and the `contentInset` etc. I'm having trouble calculating the distance to scroll.

I have the keyboard dimensions (from `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`). However I'm having trouble obtaining a useful origin value for the textfield that's being edited. The origin of the `UITextField` passed to `textFieldDidBeginEditing` isn't helpful: the value is the same regardless of the textField that's being edited. `textField.superview.origin` isn't helpful either.

**How can I obtain a useful value for the origin of the textField that's being edited?**

I'll use this value along with the keyboard height to determine the distance to scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally what I think is best is to change the frame of the table view so that it's not hidden at all by the keyboard (you can look at the keyboard frame and change the table view frame based on that). Then scroll the table view using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` so that the cell is visible.

That way `UITableView` handles what the actual content offset should be for you.

Comment: Sounds good. Any preferred method of determining which indexPath to scroll to? I think I'll scroll the tableView in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 1):

If your row heights and header heights are all the same, you could simply obtain your row value and multiply this by your row height to obtain the correct origin. If you are using variable row heights/section headers, then it becomes a bit more complicated with this approach.

The second approach, just posted by MattJGalloway as I was typing, is to change the frame of the tableview and then let the tableView scroll itself. This would be my preferred approach as well.